# How can my C# program read HTTP response header for cefsharp?

Tags: c#, httpresponse, cefsharp

I'm now using cefsharp to build a program with Chrome Browser. Before the page load, I would like to read the HTTP response header first. For the HTTP response header, I want to get the value for "Location".
I know cefsharp provide IRequestHandler.OnResourceResponse Method, but the response object only provide few property. How can I get the full http response header or just read the value of location?  Thanks.

```
cache-control: private
content-length: 132
content-type: text/html
date: Fri, 12 Apr 2019 02:14:05 GMT
location: comeIn.asp
server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
set-cookie: ASPSESSIONIDSWABBQBT=IDOHGDFDH…DPEIAJFPHIOGJ; secure; path=/
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
```

Comment: What does your code look like? http://cefsharp.github.io/api/71.0.0/html/T_CefSharp_IRequestHandler.htm has all the methods that `CEF` provides currently. `OnResourceRedirect`, `OnResourceResponse` and `OnResourceLoadComplete` are pretty much your only options. See if `OnResourceRedirect` has the location as the `newUrl` param

Comment: yes, this is only the interface, but I cannot not use CefSharp.IRequest object to get the response header for "location"

Comment: Do you mean IResponse? Is it a redirect you are trying to capture? CefSharp is just a wrapper around https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/src/master/

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you want to treat those headers with a callback that you will pass to CefSharp to treat the headers.

First, you need to declare a custom RequestHandler that overrides the method `GetResourceRequestHandler` :

```
using CefSharp;
using CefSharp.Handler;
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

namespace MachFramework.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser
{
    class HeadersProcessingRequestHandler : RequestHandler
    {
        readonly Func<NameValueCollection, bool> _headersProcessingFunc;
        public HeadersProcessingRequestHandler(Func<NameValueCollection, bool> headersProcessingFunc) => _headersProcessingFunc = headersProcessingFunc;
        protected override IResourceRequestHandler GetResourceRequestHandler(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, bool isNavigation, bool isDownload, string requestInitiator, ref bool disableDefaultHandling) => new HeadersProcessingResourceRequestHandler(_headersProcessingFunc);
    }
}
```

Then you need to declare the class returned by this override, to handle the headers:

```
using CefSharp;
using CefSharp.Handler;
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

namespace MachFramework.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser
{
    class HeadersProcessingResourceRequestHandler : ResourceRequestHandler
    {
        readonly Func<NameValueCollection, bool> _headersProcessingFunc;
        public HeadersProcessingResourceRequestHandler(Func<NameValueCollection, bool> headersProcessingFunc) => _headersProcessingFunc = headersProcessingFunc;

        protected override bool OnResourceResponse(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, IResponse response)
        {
            if (_headersProcessingFunc != null)
            {
                return _headersProcessingFunc(response.Headers);
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
 }
```

Finally you need to assign the custom RequestHandler to the CefSharp browser object that you will use:

```
browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(url.ToString());
browser.RequestHandler = new HeadersProcessingRequestHandler(headersProcessingFunc);
```

Now you will be able to treat the headers in the callback defined, the way you like. The bool return of the callback can control if the load of the request can proceed:

```
    /// To allow the resource load to proceed without modification return false. To redirect or retry the resource load optionally
    /// modify <paramref name="request"/> and return true. Modification of the request URL will be treated as a redirect. Requests
    /// handled using the default network loader cannot be redirected in this callback.
```

Comment: _headersProcessingFunc is always null in your supplied code. Any pointers? I am trying to look for m3u8 header...

Comment: Its my bad, I fixed it: 'Func<NameValueCollection, bool> headersProcessingFunc = new Func<NameValueCollection, bool>(DoIt);' and then: 'static bool DoIt(NameValueCollection headers)'